# Importing User Definitions from XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have been trying to make an export/import program but when I try to import the XML-information to the textbox it doesn't work.

C# snippet from program:

```
XmlDocument doc =  new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(open.FileName);
foreach (XmlNode x in doc.DocumentElement)
    textBox6.Text = x["Contact"].Value;
```

and the XML-file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Contact>example</Contact>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Original image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ks2F.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `InnerText` instead of `value`

```
textBox6.Text = x["Contact"].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

A breakpoint on the line

```
textBox6.Text = x["Contact"].Value;
```

should be revealing...

That's just based on visual inspection - people who supply XML as png files don't get it examined by me lol...

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlSerializer to achieve same operation.

Checkout following code.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace DemoApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NewDataSet objNewDataSet = new NewDataSet();
            Table objTable = new Table();
            objTable.Conact = "Hello";
            objNewDataSet.Table1 = objTable;

            StreamWriter objStream = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Nirav Kamani\\Desktop\\abc.xml");

            XmlSerializer objXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NewDataSet));
            objXmlSerializer.Serialize(objStream, objNewDataSet);
    }
}
```

}

Model Classes.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DemoApplication
{
    public class NewDataSet
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public Table Table1 { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace DemoApplication
{
    public class Table
    {
        public string Conact { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can serialize and deserialize easily.

For more information check out following links.

I am just giving you a better approach to achieve same operation in terms of objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx